# future continuous for a decision made at the time of phoning

Tags: future-tense

Jim (talk) was talking with his parents earlier this evening when his girlfriend from Paris (telephone) telephoned to let him know that Crossinglives & Co. (decide) had decided to merge with a company in Australia. The two companies (negociate) had been negotiating for the past month, so it really ( not be) was not much of a surprise. Of course, this (mean) means that Jim (have) will have to catch the next plane back to Paris. He (meet) **will be meeting** with his boss at this time tomorrow.

Would present continuous be used if the meeting has been fixed before Jim went to his parents

Comment: Yes, it is OK. What other options were you considering?

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't go *looking* for opportunities to use a more complex verb form, so I'd advise *He will meet her at noon* rather than *He will be meeting her at noon* for most contexts. But note that if the meeting is scheduled to last several hours, you could still use the continuous form to indicate that he'll *still* be meeting her at noon even if that meeting actually started at 9 o'clock. The simpler form *He will meet her at noon* is only suitable if that's when the meeting ***starts***.